# Cannot catch a click on Chosen close button

Tags: jquery, jquery-chosen

I am using the Chosen plugin and want to catch the event when clicking on the "X" or close buttom of an li item. But, the event does not seem to be fired or caught.

```
$(document).on('click', 'a.search-choice-close', function(e){
    alert('asd');
  });
```

This is the HTML:

```
<ul class="chosen-choices">
<li class="search-choice">
<span>a</span>
<a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="0"></a>
</li>
<li class="search-choice">
<span>asd</span>
<a class="search-choice-close" data-option-array-index="1"></a>
</li>
<li class="search-field">
<input value="Choose Stamps" class="" autocomplete="off" style="width: 25px;" type="text">
</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Are you sure that selector is correct? It's possible a parent element traps the click event and calls `stopPropagation()`.

Comment: or use of 'live' can work

Answer (score 3):

The chosen documentation describes the [Triggered Events](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/options.html#triggered-events)

To catch the event on "search-choice-close", you can try the following:

```
$('#selectID').on('change', function(change, deselected) {
    //do something
    console.log('Value Deselected');
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

To catch any change in the selection use the code

```
$("#selectId").on('change', function () {
    
    if ($("#selectId").val() === "") {

        //your code in case "X" button was pressed
        alert('asd');
    } else {

        //your code in case an option was selected
    }
});
```

when you press the "X" button on a select the same event of select change will be triggered but the select's value  `$("#selectId").val()` will be empty

Answer (score 0):

I would try two things.

1. Check that selector is correct.

   document.querySelector("a.search-choice-close");
2. check that element exist in the time when handler is registered.

Edit:
I also see that you are using jQuery. Check you don't have any jQuery error in console.

Comment: The selector is correct. The link 'a' is a dynamic one.

Comment: what do you mean by dynamic? Is added later on the page?